# Jquery animate and element on top layer

Tags: jquery

Im new i jquery and right now i try to do something with .animate.

I build grid from divs with images and i zoom one of this image. But when i zoom one, other element change position. What i should do to take this zoomed element to something like other layer - i want zoom it but on top of other images. I think that i must copy this div and then zoom it? or mayby there is something like in actionscript "depth" where i can move object to bigger depth.

My code is very simple:

```
$('.profile').hover(
function() {
    $(this).animate({ 'zoom': 1.05 }, 400);

},
function() {
    $(this).animate({ 'zoom': 1 }, 400);
});
```

Comment: First what you mean give and example and what you have tried(put codes here)?

Comment: Before zooming, you can set a `z-index` on the div, set it to a high number... and after zooming, set to a lower number.

Comment: and when i change z-index other elements will stay on their position in grid?

Comment: zoom is only supported in internet explorer

Comment: in chrome works and firefox too

Comment: @efectiva - They should all stay in the same spot if all elements have the same class value.  It should only trigger on hovering over the elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the z-index property to a high number and it will be on top of the other elements.

```
$('.profile').hover(
function() {
    $(this).css("z-index", "999").animate({ 'zoom': 1.05 }, 400);

},
function() {
    $(this).css("z-index", "0").animate({ 'zoom': 1 }, 400);
});
```

You will need to absolutely position elements in order to get them not to move when the zoom is happening. Added an example jsfiddle for positioning absolutely.

[jsFiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/2hY6W/1/)

and another jsFiddle where it uses absolute positioning inside of a relative positioned element, in case you need that:

[Another jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/2hY6W/4/)

If you just want the zoom abilities, than remove the `marginLeft`, `'width'`, and `'height'` changes, since I'm just using this as an example for how the other elements don't move, since they are absolute positioned.

And some more fun with this:  [here](http://jsfiddle.net/2hY6W/5/)

Comment: ok mayby i dont know how to say it... z-index nothing change.

Comment: Added 2 jsfiddles where you can see this working.  If this answers your question, please mark it solved!

Comment: but right now i have next problem - when i change position to absolute every element dynamicaly loaded are over another - i understand that absolute position ignore margins,float and margins in position. How can i change it? In Your example there are defined ID for div but i have them loaded dynamic.

Comment: @efectiva - You can give each div a width, even if it's being loaded dynamically, in CSS, and it will automatically take that width from the CSS Rule.  I would have to see an example of what you are talking about in order to help you any further.

Comment: And you should define a `left` css value also, depending on the width of the elements.  If they are all the same width, than this makes it easy.